# Prove $2a^Tb \leq \|a \|^2 + \|b\|_*^2$ with dual norm

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces

We know we can easily (**) prove 
$$
2a^Tb \leq  \|a \|_2^2 + \|b\|_2^2, \forall a,b 
$$
Is there a way to prove the following: 
$$
2a^Tb \leq  \|a \|^2 + \|b\|_*^2, \forall a,b 
$$

where $\|\cdot\|_*$ is the dual norm of $\|\cdot\|$.

---

(**) Proof:
$$
\| a - b \|_2^2 =(a-b)^T (a-b)  =  \|a \|_2^2 + \|b\|_2^2 - 2a^Tb \geq 0 
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, of the dual norm,
$$
a^Tb\leq \|a\|\|b\|_*.
$$
Then, using the arithmetic-geometric inequality (or $2xy\leq x^2+y^2$ if you want),
$$
2a^Tb\leq 2\|a\|\|b\|_*\leq \|a\|^2+\|b\|_*^2.
$$

Comment: Ah ... right ...